# Transfer dictionary variables from one device to another

Tags: java, android, python

I have already created a program in Python which encrypts some files. During the encryption process some variables are created which are dictionaries

params:

```
{'g_s': [5266081531416651433661684406584002665833449007031086871313393322763686898618797497739779912767380314805099010813512777194756686464038982374811725184873180, 1865373538166096236987178971699014457780608685717271312184005841385987855796673835226407327496369030143303646896055790635391049164504993264295222851491873], 'g': [3153273346490924401921357770735509187221902376155679937653089780015769160272656926328567529637107093644124348025504145114799636487950569441540320153347035, 4834978867022940740694919913223441741326591037328132861543207671498702875713061417602809102644148417542330180153669681883079888464401896479393081871748344]}
```

sk:

```
{'skid': [7331235969548792630948249970440407148448664310745618340290166798229309933305121846405410396101072690915664478261908918749302522061685493126453126652133092, 54970027359969921319000320629575823916725399592831214713981961048946307542255430571176086200448969248212121920887661847475049377949365937573523891968273]}
```

sym_key_ciphertext:

```
{'S': [6096349761997639781511128271127165448528202111188843519300947377836737433688324602464030754693475703288329477311538792012664465308347504279308677061214193, 7438058201529443530192688627913485044034292838548965528052901283146874238807363772326056038818331539850130429058817468312290699239823900238905009536717918], 'C': {'A': [1568280807213771978406922546200873379167663111862902771337811937703150380165745054441644886107007991603454924122812668789523991572594527369168879772459119, 3370767726157311769308221797645872412481288655978820252151414226636805442337319614246630647049393702661269426364901168292377714944728040255295052517703845], 'C': <integer.Element object at 0x7f6b20731768>, 'B': [3461782504510013287217732899350027954131559105811596361484375308780859157587869938575907788465225352450537995037228384432956391397106807551185208043381123, 5150831285804191790986427940904034572964428553225440882940259662587503381282019805786881209934239784912381163398110718967458740950978163907171493675403622]}}
```

sym_c:

```
<charm.toolbox.symcrypto.AuthenticatedCryptoAbstraction object at 0x776b2073690>
```

Now I want an android device (in which I can run with success python scripts), to receive these variables from the server and do the decryption of a file.So is there a way to pass all this variables without losing their contents (as I can see the sym_c variable is an object,so will it be transferred with success?)

Any advice would be helpful and deeply appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass them as JSON objects like in this example [Android JSON Parser](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_json_parser.htm)

Answer (score 0):

You need convert java object to string by use GSON which the most people are using. Link http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/